# Is there a way to acces my local project from another pc

Tags: laravel, docker

I added my laravel project to docker as it appears in the first picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVEqd.png)

And I push my images to a repository in the docker hub as it appears in the second picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxDFg.png)

Now I want to run my application on another pc, I trying to pull my images but I don't know how to run the project in the browser.

Another question is there a way to test if the project will work on another pc from my pc something like a virtual machine.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to run your Laravel project locally. If you're using Laravel 8's "Sail" tool, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sharing-your-site. If you're using Laravel Valet, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet#sharing-sites. etc.

Comment: A docker option would be [Laradock](https://laradock.io/)

Comment: @damask Laravel Sail is Docker-based.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your project to be accessed globally then the easiest way is to use [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/). It requires `node>=10.19.0`

Two simple steps to share your locally running app with others:

```
//Installing ngrok globally
npm install ngrok -g

//Expose a locally running application at port 8080 to the internet.
ngrok http 8000
```

If you want to share locally then both the PC's should be connected to the same network and you can just type the `http://{IP address of PC running APP}:{PORT}` to access the application.

To check the IP address use `ifconfig` command. Let's say it gives you 192.168.100.1, and the app is running on port 8000. To access the app on the other PC, you have to enter the following URL in the browser:

```
http://192.168.100.1:8000
```